# How to stop heads-up notification being posted via Android Code?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am building an android app that replaces the notification drawer and show notifications in its own window. I managed to show notifications on my drawer when they are posted by overriding `onNotificationPosted()` method. But, same notification is also shown by android. So,I want that notifications should be shown ONLY on my window, there are other apps who have done it,so it's not impossible. Please tell me how to override default behavior of android. Thanks in advance. :)

**EDIT**

What i want is to disable heads-up notification. Any solutions there?

Comment: Which other apps do that? The goal of your app is to replace the notification drawer completely? (for all apps?)

Comment: @FlorianBarth [Snowball](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.snowball.app&hl=en) does that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? questions like this require that you post your interceptor classes, as well as the manifest

Comment: yeah, @VipulAsri is right. Snowball does that. Infact all the apps listed on [this](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2014/04/19/11-android-apps-make-notifications-interesting/) does it.

Comment: Good Question @Bonatti . I have tried to `NotificationManager.cancelAll()` as the first thing in `onNotificationPosted` in my extending `NotificationListenerService`.

Comment: Edit your question, give us more details, post your manifest (at least the permissions), post the class that has the `onNotificationPosted()` and other classes that try to intercept system events, finally, post the target AP, and the Build/OS version you are testing on.I

Comment: @Bonatti : I need to stop heads up android notificaiton, and I seriously think  the things you asked are not required to answer this question. Even then, am posting my permissions from AndroidManifest.xml. I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: When giving information about a problem, always post on the question (press the `edit` button under it)... stackoverflow works as a repository of data, so that new/other users may search keywords and read how to resolve the problem...the Build/OS is important, the permissions is important, as well as the target API is important... finally, are you [canceling the notification on your listener?](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelNotification%28java.lang.String%29), that is what I understood you want to do

Comment: That's not what he wants @Bonatti :/ Even if you cancel ALL the notifications from the listener, they will simply be removed from the status bar and the heads-up notification will remain. Since `onNotificationPosted` fires AFTER the heads-up notification has been shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh! Looks like Android provides no way to disable heads-up notification of other apps via code.

Here is a little hack!

So, what we need is, not show any heads-up notification from any other app. To solve this, we need to understand that at one time there could be only one heads-up notification on screen.

Hack is, send your own notification right after you listen any notification being posted i.e. in `onNotificationPosted()` of a `NotificationListener` subclass.

```
this.mNotificationManager.notify(12321, new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("").setContentText("")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.transparent)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setFullScreenIntent(this.mBlankIntent, true)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build());
```

It will replace the notification of the 3rd app with your almost blank notification. Oh wow! Wait!! This looks ugly.

Ofcourse, Now we need to remove this notification before the user could even see this.

Now that you know package name of the android. You can show cancel your notification some thing like this.

```
if(packageName.equals("com.my.package")){
        mNotificationManager.cancel(12321);
        return;
    }
```

So, what we are doing is showing our notification, when any other heads up notification shows up, and then remove our own notification. All this happens so quick that user does not sees any heads-up notification, and for doing this, I did not needed to store the notification in memory even.

Comment: does either the heads-up notif or the notif that you make show up and then go away? Or are there 0 frames where they actually show up?

Comment: Yes, there are 0 frames when they will actually show up, but you have to keep it mind that should be done only for the notification with headsup, otherwise you may end up sending your own with every notification you receive.

One more thing, looks like this hack does not work with Marshmallow. So if you find something for that, let me know.

Comment: for the purposes of my app, I'm just going to ask for notification access for lollipop and ask for the do not disturb access for marshmallow instead

Comment: oh another question regarding heads-up notifs. are you just checking if the priority is >= than 1? Or have you found any instances where it could be a heads-up notif with priorty == 0?

Comment: So... Do Not Disturb mode doesn't disable heads-up notifications, which is a pain... I guess you could programmatically turn off peeking for all installed apps if that was even possible. And turn them back on afterwards. either way there's not good solutions :((((

Comment: @JasonHu : I checked if notification priority is HIGH (i.e 2) and vibration is not null.

Comment: not work for me, the heads-up notification will show accidently

Comment: Unfortunately doesn`t work on my Nexus 5X with Android 7.1.1. My headsup notification remains visible. It seems that canceling it will not remove it immediately

Answer (score 3):

In **Oreo and above OS** It is in the Notification channel Where you have to set the Priority any thing lesser than `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH` or some thing like this below stops the heads up banner.

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                                   CHANNEL_NAME, 
                                   NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
```

On **Pre-Oreo** devices, the notification priority itself helps the system to show/hide the heads up banner.
Also remember when you make this change you have to delete the app and reinstall to see the change!

Comment: This solution only works on your own notifications. The question is asking how might we prevent heads up notifications posted by other apps.

Answer (score 2):

I used `NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT` with `setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)` and it seems to work (Oneplus 3 and Note 8).

```
String channelId = "ch01";
String channelName = "Status";
int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
            channelId, channelName, importance);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
}

NotificationCompat.Builder nb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
    nb.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo);
    nb.setContentTitle(notificationText);
    nb.setContentText("");
    nb.setContentIntent(mainActivityPendingIntent);
    nb.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
    nb.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
    nb.setOngoing(true);
    nb.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: This solution only works on your own notifications. The question is asking how might we prevent heads up notifications posted by other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Set the IMPORTANCE to LOW and PRIORITY to LOW.
It work for me

```
var notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(channelId, "Call" , NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW)
            var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context,channelId)
                    .setContentTitle("Calling")
                    .setContentText("Call")
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
```

Comment: Changing the importance has other side effects like the ordering and default expansion.